# Custom List view crashing after scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

I need a simple hardcoded listview with some text and images in it. Everything works perfectly fine but when I scroll down the app crashes.

This is MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    String[] itemdate ={
            "21/02",
//there are more dates like this in here

    };

    String[] itemname ={
            "Snapchat",
//there are more strings like this in here
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.pic1,
//there are more pictures like this in here
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemdate, itemname, imgid);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my customlistadapter class.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] itemdate;
    private final String[] itemname;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemdate, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.itemdate=itemdate;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        txtTitle.setText(itemdate[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText(itemname[position]);
        return rowView;

    };
}
```

This is the logcat of the crash

```
 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:811)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:418)
            at com.peeters.ward.app.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:37)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:666)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5029)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3424)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3352)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3793)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3651)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.app
02-26 15:49:03.645    2166-2166/com.peeters.ward.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-26 15:49:03.645    2166-2166/com.peeters.ward.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.peeters.ward.app, PID: 2166
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 144000012 byte allocation with 1290600 free bytes and 1260KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:811)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:418)
            at com.peeters.ward.app.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:37)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:666)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5029)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3424)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3352)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3793)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3651)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.f
02-26 15:49:05.192    2166-2174/com.peeters.ward.app W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.159ms
02-26 15:49:05.896    2166-2166/com.peeters.ward.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2166 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you override the getCount() method in the adpater?

Comment: @PräTîkTank I posted the log cat

Comment: @Chol I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Nevermind, it is due to OutOfMemory... because fo displaying image. I don't know how to solve this, maybe use a library as glide or Picasso to display image will help

Answer (score 1):

this is due to outofmemory error use piccaso to load images like this way

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(imgid[position]).error(R.drawable.add_photo).into(myImgView);
```

to get lib http://square.github.io/picasso/

and **Try enabling large heap support**, by adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: +1 for Picasso library. Your application is running out of memory since you are loading multiple images onto it without making space for newer images. Remember even though the image might be 50 KB in size as PNG,  Android will convert it into Bitmap and display it. Picasso will handle memory allocation on its own to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the lengths of the itemdate array ,imgid array and itemname array are not the same. One of them is either smaller than the rest or larger than. Otherwise everything is alright

Comment: I counted the item and they are all the same lengths. 19 items in each array.

Comment: You have an out of memory error, the image you're trying to load into the imageview is too large (in terms of pixels) try to scale it to a smaller size.